# Is it possible to check if rows have the same value / rank inside a select script?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

My goal is to find rows with **the same rank** and replace the rank with amount of rows the duplicates take up.

If I have this result:

```
    points  place
1   300         1
2   267         2
3   245         3
4   245         3
5   240         5
```

I want it to be like this

```
    points  place
1   300         1
2   267         2
3   245         3-4
4   245         3-4
5   240         5
```

So how can I check if rows have the same value in place / points and build a case when around it? To
make it more common: Is there a way to check if 2 rows contain the same value without giving a fixed
value? So something like column1 = column1 and not column1 = 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is to use window functions to determine the count of `place` values for a given `score`.  If there is one, then no hyphen is needed:

```
select points,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by points) = 1
             then place
             else place || '-' || place || count(*) over (partition by points) - 1
        end) as new_place
from t;
```

This assumes that `place` is a string -- but that is probably not true.  So, you need some conversion:

```
select points,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by points) = 1
             then to_char(place)
             else place || '-' || place || count(*) over (partition by points) - 1
        end) as new_place
from t;
```

Actually, the `min()` place is not needed, because it is the same on each row, so:

Comment: Had some adapting to do in the else part because I got “ORA-01722: invalid number” Error. It worked when I adapted it into 
( place || '-' || (place+ (count(*) over (partition by place))-1))
Other than that it works! Thanks!

Comment: @whatever . . . Oops.  A `+` slipped in instead of a `||`.  I kept having to revise the answer because I thought the first column was part of the data.